# one to many unidirectional hibernate mapping doesn't save the child table

Tags: hibernate, annotations, one-to-many

I have two tables called `Person` and `Address`. These tables I mapped *one to many* with hibernate using annotation.

Then in my parent entity `Person` I create a `Set<Address>` to hold the child class. After that I create a set of address and set to `Person` entity and also set Person's own values.

My problem is that when I am save the parent entity child does not save in DB.

Here is my code:

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="personId")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="personName")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade =CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="personId") 
    private Set <Address> addresses;
```

**Address.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "addressId")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name="personId") 
    private int personid;
```

My DAO:

```
   public Person addNewPerson() {
    Person per = new Person();
    per.setName("aaaa person");
    Set<Address> addressSet = new HashSet<Address>();
    for(int i = 0; i<=3;i++){
        Address ad = new Address();
        ad.setAddress("aaa "+i);
        addressSet.add(ad);

    }
     per.setAddresses(addressSet);
     getHibernateTemplate().save(per );
    }
```

Here person is adding in my table but address is not saved. Why?

bidirectional it is possible, but in unidirectional is my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `personId` column is mapped twice : once to hold the foreign key to the person of the address, using the `JoinColumn` annotation, and once as a regular `int` column in the address.

Remove the `personId` field from the address. If you want to have the access to the person ID from the address, then map the association as a bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne association.

Comment: i removed personId from Address, then repeat above mentioned procedure